Handling file in a generator function
I'm to create a generator that accepts a name of the file or a fileobject, words that we're looking for in a line and stop words that tell us that we should skip this line as soon as we meet them.
I wrote a generator function, but I paid attenttion that in my realisation I can't be sure that if I open a file it will be closed afterwards, because it is not guaranteed that the generator will reach the end of its iteration.
def gen_reader(file, lookups, stopwords):
    is_file = False
    try:
        if isinstance(file, str):
            file = open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
            is_file = True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError('File not found')

    else:
        lookups = list(map(str.lower, lookups))
        stop_words = list(map(str.lower, stopwords))
        for line in file:
            original_line = line
            line = line.lower()
            if any(lookup in line for lookup in lookups) \
                    and not any(stop_word in line for stop_word in stop_words):
                yield original_line.strip()
    if is_file:
        file.close()

I was going to use context manager "with" and put the search code into it, but if I already got the file, then I'd write the same code again and it wouldn't be nice, would it?
What are your ideas how I can improve my code, I ran of them.

Aside: except FileNotFoundError: raise FileNotFoundError doesn't make all that much sense. Just don't catch the error at all and let it bubble up by itself…?

Perhaps wrapping your code in a try..finally may do what you want, with closing the file in the finally block?

Right. There should be yield 'File not found'.
Anyway, putting it in finally looks just what I did but using a variable is_file. We still can't be sure that the generator will reach its end iteration, can we?

PS. I'm also using pylint to check my code due to requires of the platform where I do this task. It doesn't like I don't use "with open....". So, I guess I should use it in my code, but I don't even know how it is going to close the file if the generator will be called once

"if I already got the file, then I'd write the same code again" Just use another function, that accepts only file object. Your wrapper accepts filename or file object. If you got a file name, use context manager to open the file and pass the file object to the inner function. If you got a file object, run the inner function immediately.

You could write a context managed class that is iterable like this:
from pathlib import Path
from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import TextIO, Self


class Reader:
    def __init__(self, filename: Path, lookups: list[str], stopwords: list[str]):
        self._lookups: set[str] = {e.lower() for e in lookups}
        self._stopwords: set[str] = {e.lower() for e in stopwords}
        self._fd: TextIO = filename.open()

    def __enter__(self) -> Self:
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_) -> None:
        self._fd.close()

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[str]:
        for line in self._fd:
            words: set[str] = {e.lower() for e in line.split()}
            if (self._lookups & words) and not (self._stopwords & words):
                yield line.rstrip()


with Reader(Path("foo.txt"), ["world"], ["banana"]) as reader:
    for line in reader:
        print(line)

Now let's assume that foo.txt looks like this:
hello world
banana world
goodbye my friend

Then the output would be:
hello world

Thus we ensure that the file descriptor is properly closed at the appropriate point.
Note also the use of sets for optimum performance when checking against the lookups and stop words

Thanks. It looks fine, especially using sets to check lookups and stop words.

You might as well make the Reader object iterable itself, with gen renamed __iter__. I'm not sure there's much benefit of making the file opening lazy with the fd property. Why not just open the file in __init__ and unconditionally close it in __exit__?

@Blckknght I have rewritten my original answer in the hope that it meets your standards

Looks great now! It was already pretty good, but this version is pretty much exactly what I would have done myself.

Maybe it would be better if you only pass file object to your function and then your can close the file object any time
def gen_reader(file, lookups, stopwords):
    lookups = list(map(str.lower, lookups))
    stop_words = list(map(str.lower, stopwords))
    for line in file:
        original_line = line
        line = line.lower()
        if any(lookup in line for lookup in lookups) \
                and not any(stop_word in line for stop_word in stop_words):
            yield original_line.strip()

# an usage example
with open("xxfile", "r") as f:
    for line in gen_reader(f, ["w1", "w2",...], ["st1", "st2", ...]):
        # do something with line you have found
        ...  
# file would be closed here 


Unfortunately, the generator must accept both a file name and a fileobject according to the task
